# cardinality of the set of all prime factors of 120

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

I need to find the cardinality of the set of all prime factors of $120$.

Will it be $16$? Since the set of all prime factors of  $120$ will always have $16$ elements i.e $\{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 20, 24, 30, 40, 60, 120\}$.

Or is this a trick question and requires a proof to answer?

Comment: You seem to have written all the factors down. You need only the prime factors : this is not a trick question, do not worry. If you give me a set and prove that it is the set of prime factors of $120$, we are done. So you'd need to prove that every number in that set is prime and a factor of $120$, but also prove that no other number is a factor of $120$. (Note : I am *not* aware of conventions regarding primality of the number $1$ : you will need to consult whoever gave you this question for the answer to that, though I like to think the answer is no).

Comment: The question asks for all the **prime** factors, not all divisors. The only "trick" is knowing what 'prime' means.

Answer (score 3):

> Definition: A integer $p>1$ is a prime number if it unique divisors are $p$ and $1$.

**Fundamental theorem of arithmetic** :

Every integer $n>1$  either is a prime number itself or can be represented as the product of prime numbers and that, moreover, this representation is unique, up to (except for) the order of the factors.

*Solution:*

With the definition above and the theorem, we can always find the prime factors of any integer $n$ (by fundamental theorem of arithmetic) .

Notice that we can write
$$120= 2^3\times 3 \times 5$$
and Hence the prime factors are the set $$S=\lbrace 2,3,5\rbrace$$
as well.

Comment: so the cardinality is 3. cool thanks Brien.

Comment: Your welcome i´m glad of help you

Comment: +1... But your def'n of prime is flawed, although the same kind of logical flaw appears in many types of def'ns in many books.

Comment: You are correct, I´m gonna switch the definition, but since the person who made the question doesn´t have a lot of experience I decide put a classical definition that a non mathematician know usually.